Conditions on the constants for two "linear" functions to commute under the operation of function composition
Let $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ be any complex numbers such that $a \neq 0$ and $c \neq 0$; let the functions $f \colon \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $g \colon \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be the functions defined by
$$
f(x) \colon= ax+b \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad  g(x) \colon= cx+d \qquad \mbox{ for each } x \in \mathbb{C}. \tag{0}
$$
Then
$$ 
f \circ g = g \circ f \tag{1} 
$$
if and only if
$$
f\big( g(x) \big) = g\big( f(x) \big) \qquad \mbox{ for each } x \in \mathbb{C},
$$
that is,
$$
a g(x) + b = c f(x) + d \qquad \mbox{ for each } x \in \mathbb{C},
$$
which then becomes
$$
a (cx+d) + b = c (ax+b) + d \qquad \mbox{ for each } x \in \mathbb{C},
$$
which simplifies to
$$
acx + (ad + b) = ac x + (bc + d) \qquad \mbox{ for each } x \in \mathbb{C},
$$
and hence
$$
ad + b = bc + d,
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
ad - bc = d - b. \tag{2} 
$$
Is the  condition (2) the most general condition for (1) to hold? If so, is there a more illuminating way that we can express this condition? If not, then what are the most general necessary and sufficient condition(s) for (1) to hold?

Nice question! That is the condition, but it's not a very enlightening way of writing it. Here's a more conceptual approach. If $a \neq 1$, then $f(x) = ax + b$ has a unique fixed point, which is the unique solution to $ax_0 + b = x_0$, namely
$$x_0 = \frac{b}{1 - a}.$$
Then $f(x)$ can be thought of geometrically as a rotation and a scaling (by $\theta$ and $r$, where $a = re^{i \theta}$ is the polar form of $a$) around this fixed point. This way of thinking makes it clear that a sufficient condition for two such operations to commute is that they have the same fixed point; this gives
$$\frac{b}{1 - a} = \frac{d}{1 - c}$$
which you can see is equivalent to what you wrote after clearing denominators. We need to handle the case $a = 1, b \neq 0$ separately; in this case $f$ is just a translation, and any two translations commute, but translations never commute with rotations (you can check that conjugating with a translation has the effect of translating the fixed point). So another sufficient condition for commutativity is that $a = c = 1$, which is also consistent with what you wrote. Finally we could have $a = 1, b = 0$, in which case $f(x) = x$ commutes with everything, which is also consistent with what you wrote.
The remaining question is why these sufficient conditions are necessary. This is a little trickier to see conceptually but you can do it by reasoning geometrically about what happens when you conjugate by a rotation (it has the effect of rotating the fixed point).
